React Native: App build succeeds but crashes immediately on Android emulator
I'm using React Native CLI (version 0.72) and after successfully building the app with
npm run android,

the app opens in the Android emulator but immediately closes without any error messages in the terminal. Here are the key points
The build completes successfully with no errors in the terminal (BUILD SUCCESSFUL).



**
Running on Android Emulator (x86).**
Logcat shows several entries but nothing obvious about why the app crashes. One notable entry:
Unexpected CPU variant for x86: x86_64.

Recreating the emulator.

Clearing Gradle cache.

Invalidating Android Studio caches.


Versions

React Native (0.72)

Android Studio

Android SDK version (SDK 33)

Node.js, npm


My computer is old but in other React Natives CLI project ran android studio ok.
Any ideas on how to resolve this issue or improve emulator compatibility?
✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android

Versions found: 30.0.3, 35.0.0
Version supported: 33.0.0



Logcat entry about an "Unexpected CPU variant for x86: x86_64" suggests there might be a compatibility issue between the emulator configuration and your app's build.
You could try the following

Check Emulator Configuration:

Ensure your emulator is correctly set up for x86 emulation. The log suggests there might be a mismatch with x86_64. You can create a new emulator specifically targeting the x86 ABI instead of x86_64 to see if it resolves the issue.


React Native and Dependency Versions:

Since you mentioned your build is using an older version of the Android SDK (33.0.0 required but 30.0.3 and 35.0.0 found), it might help to install the exact version needed or update your build.gradle to match one of the existing versions.


Clean Build:

Clean your project and rebuild it. You can do this via:
cd android
./gradlew clean


Then, run the app again:
cd ..
npm run android




Detailed Logcat Output:

Examine the Logcat output more closely right after the crash occurs. Look for any exceptions or errors that might indicate what's causing the crash. You can filter Logcat by your app’s package name to get more relevant logs.


Update Project Dependencies:

Make sure all project dependencies are compatible with the version of React Native you're using. This includes any third-party libraries.


Testing on a Physical Device:

If possible, test the app on a physical device to see if the issue is specific to the emulator environment.


Emulator Hardware Profile:

Try changing the hardware profile of the emulator. Sometimes certain configurations can cause issues with specific apps.



